# Adding a dynamic generated item on a view (from it's controller) which is a toolbar

Tags: extjs, view, controller, extjs4

I'm having problem with a "stupid" part of the code which, for me, should works straight but I don't understand why it's giving me problems:

**controller**

```
Ext.define('FedertrekDesktop.controller.Taskbar', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

  views: [
    'taskbar.Toolbar',
    //'taskbar.Button'
  ],

  showWindow: function(windowName, image, title) {
    //var btn = Ext.create('FedertrekDesktop.view.taskbar.Button', windowName, image, title);
    //this.getView('taskbar.Toolbar').insert(0, btn);
    console.log("tmp: "+this.getView('taskbar.Toolbar').printMsg());
    //console.log('msg: '+this.getView('taskbar.Toolbar').getName());
    console.log('Create window '+windowName+' '+image);
  }
});
```

**view**

```
Ext.define('FedertrekDesktop.view.taskbar.Toolbar', {
  extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
  alias : 'widget.taskbartoolbar',

  items: [
    {
      xtype: 'tbfill'
    },
    {
      xtype: 'tbseparator'
    },
    {
      xtype: 'button',
      enableToggle: true,
      text: 'Tasks'
    }
  ],

  printMsg: function() {
    console.log("printmsg");
  }
});
```

Actually I'm just testing by trying to call that custom function (printMsg). However it seems that the function is missing, I don't really understand why. What am I missing here?

**ERROR**: this.getView("taskbar.Toolbar").printMsg is not a function

Any suggestion appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself with refs

The result code is this one:

```
Ext.define('FedertrekDesktop.controller.Taskbar', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

  views: [
    'taskbar.Toolbar',
    'taskbar.Button'
  ],

  refs: [
    {
      ref: 'taskbarView',
      selector: 'taskbartoolbar'
    }
  ],

  showWindow: function(windowName, image, title) {
    //var btn = Ext.create('FedertrekDesktop.view.taskbar.Button', windowName, image, title);
    //var btn = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', { text: "Bla" });
    //this.getView('taskbar.Toolbar').insert(0, btn);
    //var tmp = this.getView('taskbar.Toolbar').create();
    //tmp.add(btn);
    var tmp = this.getTaskbarView();
    tmp.printMsg();
    //console.log('msg: '+this.getView('taskbar.Toolbar').getName());
    console.log('Create window '+windowName+' '+image);
  }
});
```

As I understood, ExtJS doesn't create references to views in you controller as I thought, you have to specify them!

They offer the powerful feature of refs which are documented on [Controller](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller) and on [ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery)

After using them I feel satisfact with my code. The one I posted is just an example, but it's not hard from that point to effectively add something to the view by using *insert* method.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.getView('taskbar.Toolbar').create().printMsg()
```

Does this work? According to the documentation, `getView(String name)` returns Ext.Base, which doesn't have your printMsg function.

Comment: Mh as I understood getView returns the class, not the instance. That's the main problem. How can I actually fetch the instance of an existent view controller by the current controller? (is in the views array).

Comment: An existent view controll- **ed** by the current controller

Comment: It works but it creates a new view, doesn't reference the existing one. Any possibility to reference the existing one?

Comment: I see I see, I don't think it is the right way to get the reference using the "view", according to the doc, the "view" config variable is essentially the same thing as "requires".
you are probably better off just try to getting the component by its name or id. Or try the "ref" variable in the "Controller" class. How to use "ref" is outlined in the API.

Comment: Mh thanks for this suggestion. I'm asking you another thing (sorry for this): How am I supposed to interact with the view from a controller? I mean, I don't think my approach is correct thinking about rails, I should pass some params to view and that should "redraw" itself. Which is the correct way to handle view in this case? Should I interact with a model (containing a list of <buttons> or at least params for them) which when updated will auto update the view?

Comment: I would prefer the latter approach, where the view handles its own rendering. The controller can add items to the view, but the view should make a decision for itself whether or not to re-render.